# Turn On/Off keyboard backlight on Python

Tags: python, keyboard, light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to programmatically turn on the Macbook Pro's keyboard backlight for individual keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124181/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-turn-on-the-macbook-pros-keyboard-backlight)

Is some way to toggle backlight of keyboard with python?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991813/changing-brightness-of-the-macbookpro-keyboard-backlight  The actual article it links to: http://www.osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/  Another relevent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124181/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-turn-on-the-macbook-pros-keyboard-backlight

Comment: Yes but it uses Objective C that is used on mac programming i`m nedd this in all OS.